Smell of Crude/Fuel Oil when acid-treating belemnoides
I sometimes find belemnoids from the late jurassic in an old limestone quarry, so to clean them up a bit and make them more visually appealing, I sometimes treat them with 10% acetic acid to get rid of any limestone residue on the surface. That usually works pretty well, however I started noticing, that at least upon the first treatment of the belemnoid fossil with the acid a quite strong odor resembling fuel oil like you would smell at a port or other heavy oils appears. This lasts for about 15 minutes, then the belemnoid stops producing any odor. This does however not happen if i dissolve a piece of limestone from the same quarry without a belemnoid in the acid, so it must have to do with the fossil. Has anyone else noticed anything alike, maybe even with other fossils? Or does anyone have an explanation why this is happening or which substances are created or set free by the acid?
Thanks in advance

Perhaps the carbon from the organism or the acid environment caused by the decomposition caused there to be carbon around the fossil which compressed into crude oil
